# Stop Jenkins Build

Tags: jenkins, github

We have recently moved to GitHub. But we are facing issue as,

1. whenever any user is making any commit to the file it is automatically triggering build in Jenkins.

Now the issue is, If more that one developer is working on same project and they are making the commit. so for every commit, Jenkins build is being triggered.

How can we stop this automatic build in Jenkins whenever commit is made?

Answer (score 0):

If you have enabled Github webhook, disabled it.
[image]
or

if you have Poll SCM Turn ON disabled it on the Jenkins Job
[image]